How widely globally are compounding pharmacies allowed to make "Ozempic knockoffs" and similar?
Bloomberg is reporting (avaoiding paywall) that in the US compounding pharmacies are allowed to make their own versions of patent protected drugs if "the treatments is in short supply".  This is described by the American Pharmacists Association:

Compounding is the creation of a pharmaceutical preparation—a drug—by a licensed pharmacist to meet the unique needs of an individual patient (either human or animal) when a commercially available drug does not meet those needs. A patient may not be able to tolerate the commercially available drug, the exact preparation needed may not be commercially available, or a patient may require a drug that is currently in shortage or discontinued.

This is being used, some are saying exploited, to provide their own versions of drugs such as the diabetes medications Ozempic from Eli Lilly and Wegovy from Novo Nordisk that have been used for weight loss.  This is lucrative for the pharmacies and popular but dangerous for patients.
I assume this is an exception in US patent law, but I do not know. How widely globally is this legal?  Are compounding pharmacies in the EU, UK and other areas of the world allowed to produce and sell their own versions of these popular drugs while they are in short supply?

Why is it dangerous for patients? I would assume the replacement by the pharmacist is made to the same safety standards as the original and if chemically it is a direct copy, the efficacy has already been tested.

@quarague From the linked Bloomberg article "the third dose that she thinks caused her trouble. Acne erupted on her cheeks, nose, chin and forehead.  Acne isn’t listed as a side effect of the FDA-approved formulation. Her doctor suggested it might have been a problem with the medicine itself. The drugs were produced without going through the rigorous approval process required for brand-name or generic medications." [Heavily editted]

There is no loophole in U.S. patent law for compounding pharmacies. A patent owner can try to stop anyone who makes, sells, offers for sale, imports or uses their invention.
A closer look at the web site you quote from says “Compounding does not include making copies of commercially available drug products, as this is not allowed by law.” That statement is not precisely  correct because being commercially available  is not the standard.

I believe authorization for making compounded drugs is authorized by the Food Drug & Cosmetics Act.  There are standards for what is allowed in the act, and FDA regulations include drugs that have a shortage.  There may be litigation about shortages but the underlying principles are fairly well established.

@TigerGuy - any idea where in the code that is stated ?

@TigerGuy The intent for compounding pharmacies is to make lower-risk modifications to existing drugs. For example, grinding pills up and make a liquid for a patient who can't swallow pills. This may occur because there isn't a liquid version or it's out of stock. This likely does not infringe on the original drug patent due to exhaustion. What's going on here is compounding pharmacies are way pushing the limit due to ambiguous regulation and synthesizing essentially new drugs.

@GeorgeWhite there are rquirements in the act itself https://www.fda.gov/drugs/human-drug-compounding/section-503a-federal-food-drug-and-cosmetic-act but it also says the Secretary can issue regulations, which I assume is what the shortage component uses.

@user71659, while there are things like removing a dye, by itself those changes would run afoul of patents if not for the FD&CA.  Manufacturers are not suing the compounders, they are going to Congress & the FDA to try to remove the protections.  Why I know this is that Ozempic is literally unobtainable where I live, but its manufacturer fights the compounders.  I take a compounded shot of it.

The linked text didn’t include the word patent. If you think there is a provision that suspends patent rights you might look in the patent code. You will see something g about “march in” rights but it is for pandemics etc. and hasn’t been invoked. The FDA can regulate pharmacists but and it let then get around FDA rules. It can’t declare patent law does not apply. Unless you find a  provision other than the linked one.

As user71659 points out, the compounding pharmacies typically bypass the patents via the exhaustion exhaustion doctrine. They buy a (patented) drug from the manufacturer, then modify it to suit the patients needs. The FDA protection linked by Tiger Guy carves out a limited exception to the laws against adulterating medicine, but says nothing about patents.
